# html неполная рамка

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как можно реализовать в html и css такие полуокружности под фотографиями? Border тут не подойдёт, как я понимаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**минимум кода**

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://libymax.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/jobs.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: кода минимум, но не по макету же, на изображении скругленные края, а у вас нет

Comment: в этом то и была сложность, странно, что выбрали ответом..

Answer (score 11):

Для скругленных краев добавьте к диву псевдоэлементы before и after:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  
  position:relative;
}
div:before,div:after{
  content:'';
  height:9px;
  width:9px;
  border-radius:200%;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:19px;
}
div:before{left:18px}
div:after{right:18px}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://libymax.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/jobs.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Исключительно ради точности - ::before и ::after - это псевдоэлементы.